# View should appear from under another view

Tags: ios

I have 2 views : the default VC view and another view 'view2'.Now I want a functionality where I can see the 'view2' appearing under the default view and the frame of current view should resize accordingly.I am new to iOS but I know the basic concepts well.So I have done some research and here is what I'm trying to do.

Clicking a textField should show view2 as mentioned above.

```
    textFieldDidBeginEditing:
```

This the delegate that will be used.

```
    [textField resignFirstResponder];//keyboard
    textField.inputView = view2;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                     animations:^{
                         _mySubView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 300,self.view.frame.size.width , 320);
                     }];//For animation
```

But I am not able to get the perfect functionality just as I have mentioned above.

Comment: Are you saying that you have a view that is not managed by a view controller?

Comment: I would think you want your VC view to contain two child views. The one on top and the one behind. Use constraints to position these. In code adjust the constraints to their new positions and animate the constraint change by putting `[self.view layoutIfNeeded]` in the animation block.

Comment: Can I get the code so that I can analyse that....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlast I'm done with it and I found 2 methods to do it:The first method is based on creating an outlet of the desired constraint and the second method is using the 'NSLayoutConstraint' class method:

```
    +(instancetype)constraintWithItem:(id)view1 attribute:(NSLayoutAttribute)attr1 relatedBy:(NSLayoutRelation)relation toItem:(id)view2 attribute:(NSLayoutAttribute)attr2 multiplier:(CGFloat)multiplier constant:(CGFloat)c;
```

Actually this method is based on the formula A = B * m +C ,where
       m = multiplier and C = constant.

So let's say I have one view 'view1' that is placed at the centre right now and the default viewController view 'view'.Make view1 hidden at the start.Now if I want a functionality where I click my textField and I should see my view2 appearing from the bottom.So what I need to do is set the 'Y' coordinate of my view2 something beyond the height of my default view:

```
    view2.frame = CGRectMake(0,self.view.frame.size.height+someValue,width,height);
```

After this just use the above method as:

```
     NSLayoutConstraint *view2Position = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_grayView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0f constant:someNegativeValue];
[self.view addConstraint:view2Position];//Make sure the negative value contains whole view(view2) on the view(view)
```

And to add the animations to it,add the below method within the animation block:

```
    [view2 layoutIfNeeded];
```

So,basically here:
A = view2
B = view
m = multiplier 1.0f;//here it gets multiplied by bottom edge position of view
c = some negative value

Answer (score 0):

You need to make subview of your view2 in your current view controller.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                     animations:^{
                          View2 *_mySubView=[View2 alloc]init];

                         _mySubView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 300,self.view.frame.size.width , 320);
                         [self.view addsubview:_mySubview];

                     }];
```

Comment: Well the thing is that I am already placing my subView in storyboard at the bottom.Now it should appear to come from the bottom of the screen and should move my view up.How to do that?Shall I set its 'Y' coordinate beyond its height and again 'Y' to some value in the view?

Comment: Use just need to set your y frame of subview using_mySubview.frame.origin.y=_mysubview.frame.origin.y-30 (set value according to how up you want your view.)

Comment: Yup I have done that!!!But I want a bit more than that.Let me elaborate:
view1(not the default controller view) is at the bottom of the page in storyboard.View2 is above view1 and is hidden.Now when I click text field view2 should come from beneath view1 and accordingly view1 should move up.Now I know that I need to set 'Y' coordinates for both the views.But since I have these views in storyboard,I won't be able to change the frame of these two views(I can if I uncheck the 'use auto layout' option in storyboard).So for that I need to set the constraints at runtime.

Comment: And that's what I haven't studied yet.I need to study that and I will be back with the solution.Thanks a lot :-)